# What does "trait" mean?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, terminology, valuation-rings

Looking at some French papers, it seems that the word "trait" is often used to refer to the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring $A$.

Does anyone know what the translation of this should be? Is it supposed to be a word conveying some geometric intuition for $\text{Spec}(A)$?

Comment: A link to the relevant papers could be helpful to figure out the actual English equivalent.

Comment: https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Theorie-de-Hodge-I.pdf in Section 8

Comment: In which page does the word "trait" appear?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Page 428, "Soit $V$ le spectre ... (un *trait hensélien*)".

Answer (score 4):

This means a little segment of line: not a point, but the smallest thing after a point.

This also means "feature", which could be another reason to use this for a spectrum.

See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trait for the etymology.

Comment: It is also the equivalent of "stroke", as in the stroke order while writing Japanese kanji.

Comment: While the explanation as "the smallest line segment larger than a point" catches the geometry quite clearly, I do not understand your remark about "feature".

Answer (score 3):

Someone means something as $\text{Spec}(k[[x]])$: his spec is $0$ and $(x)$, so it is an enlargement of the point $(0)$ of $\text{Spec}(k)$, for this reason it could be named as a "trait". It is inside the longer line $\text{Spec}(k[x])= \mathbb{A}_k^1$: in this sense you can think at it as the "really little" piece of the affine line around $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be analogous to an open unit disk:
$$D = \{|z| < 1\}$$
See:

http://176.58.104.245/NOTES/Dobbiaco-2014-06/Illusie-Dobbiaco.pdf (Page 6)

https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/files/2015/02/Oxford-clay-2017.pdf (Page 11)